# Define a MIME type for .TXT files for Tika

Tags: mime-types, apache-tika, tika-server

I want to define the MIME type of *.txt files: `text/txt`, so that Tika can apply a more specific parser than the one used for `text/plain` files.

The glob `*.txt` is included in the definition of the type `text/plain` in `tika-mimetypes.xml`. Moreover, it seems to me that you cannot redefine a MIME type in `custom-mimetypes.xml`, only add new globs or magic patterns. Additionally, if I define the `text/txt` type in `tika-mimetypes.xml` as a subtype of `text/plain` with only the glob `*.txt`, Tika still detects a txt file as `text/plain`.

Is it absurd to define a subtype of `text/plain` only for txt files? If not, is it possible to define it only with `custom-mimetypes.xml`? If not, what is the easiest way to extend tika so that it can parse txt files differently than (let's say) STEP 3D CAD .stp files or .cfg files?

The use case in detail: I have a large source of data composed of (recursive) archives. Some plain text files are huge and I don't want Tika to parse them. However, I want to keep all the txt files.

**Edit**: specify that I don't want to keep .cfg files either (`*.cfg` is a glob of `text/plain`)

Comment: Why not register your own mimetype for your CAD files, then provide your own custom parser for the CAD mimetype?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I fear this is not an option for me because I don't want to include .cfg files. In fact, the only plain text files that I want to keep are the .txt files (I updated the question).

Comment: Ah, right now you can't easily. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-2554 to track a Tika improvement change to make that possible. Short term you'd need a custom Detector class which uses the filename to do your custom type behaviour

Comment: Thanks for creating the issue! You state that "The only change would be for detection, where a more specific type would be returned" but I don't even achieved to change type detection. Anyway, I will get round the issue by using the rmeta route of tika-parser. This gives me full control to filter afterwards which files I want to keep based on the resource extension. The downsides are that I can't use Tika's advanced mimetype detection features (magic and statistical tests, but I don't need them here) and this parses unnecessary files. I'm happy with that!

Comment: With the change done (which it is for config on git head!), you can register a different parser for `text/x-config` to catch your `.cfg` files differently to plain text etc

Comment: Wow that's amazing!